# How to separate numbers with commas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to separate given numbers with commas individually . I read other stack overflow post that didn't help me. How to add commas between them ?

```
numbers = 456782 # output => 4,5,6,7,8,2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to string, and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a comma:

```
output = ','.join(str(numbers))
```

Since `str` is an iterable of length one `str`s, it's a valid input to `str.join`, which will put a comma between every character in the original string.

The (much) slower equivalent code that spells out each step would be:

```
numbers_str = str(numbers)
output = numbers_str[0]    # Get first character by itself
for digit in numbers_str[1:]:
    output += ',' + digit  # Each subsequent character is prefixed with comma
```

but `join` does this as a single function call, with C level access, to run much faster.

Comment: I tried but i'm getting value error with base int 10 
error message :output_int = int(output)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4,5,6,7,8,9,2'

my code :
numbers = 4567892
n_str = str(numbers)
output = ",".join(n_str)
output_int = int(output)

Comment: @Naveen: You can't convert the result to `int` like that; it's a string now, with commas in it (which is what you asked for). If you want a sequence of the digits themselves (which are only separated with commas in literal form, there is no "comma" in the actual structure), not a string, you'd do `output_ints = [int(digit) for digit in str(numbers)]` (or slightly faster for huge inputs, `output_ints = list(map(int, str(numbers)))`) to make a `list`.